# Refresh pivot table in xlsx file without using office

Tags: python, excel, bash, vbscript

I need to refresh pivot table in an xlsx file using **any programming language** without using Office. 
As I need to run it on production server where MS Office won't be installed.

So the code should not be dependent on any Office product.

I was trying using Python but my code need MS Excel.

Comment: It's unclear what *"refresh"* means here.  Please show some sample input, and the desired output.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change cell values in an XLS file? If so, is .NET an option? I'm somewhat familiar with doing this in C#.